# To list out file size by largest size and last modified date by one user in Linux

Tags: linux

in redhat linux, I want to list out the size in GB for every folder in this directory called /usertemp

There are about 100 folders in the folder which could be created/generated by various users.
What I want is to only list out the user "adm_dev" in the most recent/last modified date and display the file size in GB (Best is to sort by file size in GB and last modified in descending order)

Is this doable?

I tried du -l but i dont have the option to sort it by last modified + largest file size by adm_dev.

Comment: Please mark my answer as solved if it resolved you problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will list directories owned by adm_dev in /usertemp and perform a du command on them, sorting by filesize in descending order.

```
find /usertemp -maxdepth 1 -user adm_dev -type d | xargs -I{} du -sh -- {} | sort -h -r
```